# Decrypting widevine DRM protected video in android using MediaDrm

Tags: android, encryption, drm, mediaextractor, widevine

I am trying to decrypt widevine DRm protected media file using Android's MediaDrm API.
But MediaDrm is instantiated using UUId( of  DRM-scheme). Android developer site says

"App accesses the DRM-scheme-identifying UUID, typically from metadata in the content, and uses this UUID to construct an instance of a MediaDrm object that is able to support the DRM scheme required by the content".
(www.developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDrm.html).

So I tried to get UUID using MediaExtractor.getpsshInfo() but it returned a null object.
Then I tried DrmManagerClient.getMetadata(uri of media content) but again this method also returned **null**.

I tried this on the follwing widevine demo uri:

content URL: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/wvmedia/starz_main_720p_6br_tp.wvm
Licence server: https://license.uat.widevine.com/getlicense/widevine

although after aquiring rights  using DrmManagerClient API I am able to play the video in Android's native MediaPLayer( VideoView) but I want to decrypt the media file using Android's MediaDrm API  and want to get unencrypted  data ,which I am not able to do because I am not getting proper UUID value.
Can someone point me in the right direction to achieve this.

Or Can some one help me in accessing a DRM scheme - UUID value?

Thanks

Comment: I tried to integrate google widevine in android but failed. I didn't find any help or sample code for how to integrate it.
Could you please guide me how to achieve that? Which information or id or access do I have to need to integrate it?
I want to test widevine with your content URL.
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mediaDRM is designed for EME Common Encryption playback.  See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDrm.html

The Widevine content you have listed is not in the Common Encryption format and therefore, is incompatible.